# MVC Kendo Combobox selected item value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using Kendo Combo Box in my view. I bind this combo box to a Enum type in my model. But when I run application and change the values in drop down. Always only the first value is selected and passed to the model.

```
//MyModel
public class Mymodel
{
   public IsPerson IsPerson { get; set; }
}

public enum IsPerson 
    {
          yes,
          No
    }
//index.cshtml

 @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(x => x.MyModel.IsPerson )
        .Name("IsPerson ")
        .Placeholder("Select IsPerson ..")
                .BindTo(Enum.GetNames(typeof(App2_MVC.Models.IsPerson))))
```

what is the reason? Even if I select "No" in dropdown I am getting selected item as '0' so value 'Yes'??

Comment: you don't need x=>x.MyModel.IsPerson, just x=>x.IsPerson ,check this link for more information http://www.telerik.com/forums/dropdownlist-with-enums

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of binding the combo box to enum bind it to object of key, value pair. Also define the "DataTextField and DataValueField" to get proper value of selected element.

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.IsPerson)
 .Placeholder("----- Select -----")
 .DataTextField("Value")
 .DataValueField("Key")
 .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("MyActionMethod", "Controller")))
)
```

Action method should return IEnumerable< Model > object where "Model" is of "Key and value" pair. i.e.

```
public class Model
{
    public string Value{ get; set; }

    public int Key{ get; set; }
}
```

In controller:

```
public ActionResult MyActionMethod()
    {
        var model= new Model 
                {
                    Value = "xyz",
                    Key = 1
                };
                var selectList = new List<Model>();
                selectList.Add(model);
                // Also can add multiple objects
                // Or add your database code to fetch the values from db table

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

As per Your code:

```
     @model myapplication.Models.MyDetails

       <div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("PostMymethod", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @(Html.Kendo().PanelBar()
    .Name("Intro")
    .ExpandAll(false)
    .ExpandMode(PanelBarExpandMode.Single)
    .Items(items =>
    {
        items.Add()
            .Text("Jquery")
            .Content(@<text>

                @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(x => x.sismember)
                            .DataTextField("value")
                    .DataValueField("key")
                    .DataSource(source =>
                    {
                        source.Read(read =>
                        {
                            read.Action("MyActionMethod", "Home");
                        });
                    })
                    )

            </text>);

    })
        )
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="savebtns">
                    <input type="submit" name="Command" value="Save" id="savebtn" class="=btn" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
    }
</div>
```

Model Property:

```
public class MyDetails
{
 public string sismember { get; set; }//this is the property im binding to combobox
}
```

where Ismember is a class which has key and value:

```
public class IsMember
    {
        public string value { get; set; }

        public int key { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to get seleted combox value in this controller : MyController

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PostMymethod(MyDetails myDataModel,string command)
        {
            if (command == "Save")
            {
                return View("Home", myDataModel);
            }

           return View("Home", myDataModel);
        }
}
```

Comment: how to get the selected value of this combo box ??

Comment: Use:

var selectedValue = $('#IsPerson').data('kendoComboBox').value();

Note: "IsPerson" is  the model property for which combo-box is defined.

Also, if this answer has solved your problem please accept the answer and close the question and for other doubts raise new questions.
Glad to help you.:)

Comment: I want to get selected combo box value in "IsModel" property.But I am getting only NULL always. Only the selected value is not binding to model in any way..need ur help @Satya Ranjan Sahoo

Comment: One more thing .is it necessary to write script function to get selected value I want to get selected value with out any script function.

Comment: It same as what ever u posted..but in dropdown value id 'undefined'

Comment: I will be glad if I can help you in any respect. But here the conversation is getting longer by adding comments. better if you can join me in google hangout "satyaranjan219@gmail.com".

Comment: I have removed the ".Name" property from the dropdown code. Check if works now or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65370/discussion-between-7783-and-satya-ranjan-sahoo).

Comment: Excellent approach !